# How to update my arraylist without refreshing page?

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax

I have implemented a simple program known as foodlist which is a array list. i used to add food items to list through ajax. Everything works fine. but i want to update the list items when i insert food items to the array. 
This is my app.js file

```
app.post('/add', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body.item); 
    foods.push(req.body.item);
    console.log(foods);
    res.render('index',{order:foods});
});
```

index.ejs

```
<form >
    <input type="text" name="game" id="title">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<span id="succ_msg"></span><br>

<% if(typeof order !== "undefined") {
    for (var i = 0; i< order.length; i++) { %>
    <div id="champ">
        <span><%= order[i] %></span>
    </div>
<% } }%>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var title = $('#title').val();
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/add',
            data: {
                item: title
            },
            success: function(result) {
                $('#title').val("");
                $('#succ_msg').html("Success");
                setInterval(function() {
                    $('#champ').load() //here is my problem
                }, 1000);
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log('Error');
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Any ideas

Comment: What exactly is your problem? do you get errors? is the list empty?

Comment: Hey, my prob is when i add data into arraylist it didn't update on front view without refreshing.  After i refreshed my page it also updated.

Comment: My basic qus is how to update a list which is displaying on front page without refreshing? can you say answer depends on my code that i've showed above

Comment: Simple: You must propagate `result` to html page. see here https://stackoverflow.com/q/41001619/1194525

Comment: Please show your client code. The client would need to make the request, then inject the response data into its DOM.